# How to install Python 3.8 for use in PyCharm 2021.3?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am going to take the TensorFlow Developer Certificate exam. The exam requires

1. PyCharm 2021.3
2. Python 3.8

On my laptop, I usually use python via Spyder on Anaconda

I downloaded PyCharm 2021.3, but I can't set up a new proj with Base Interpreter Python 3.8. It states Python executable is not found.

When I try to download Python 3.8 from https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/
the executable files are not found there.

So how do I install Python 3.8 for use with PyCharm 2021.3?

Answer (score 0):

Try out doing these steps:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

worked for me.

Lmk.

Samu

Comment: Thanks but how do I download & install Python 3.8?

Comment: really sorry I'm only answering now. I would redirect you to the official page python.org: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: This guide could also be very helpful in case you are looking to update to newer versions: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-python

Answer (score 0):

You can see the version of your interpreter from the bottom right corner, otherwise you will see the message to **No interpreter**, you can click on the Python version and follow these steps:

Click your version or/No interpreter>>Add Interpreter>>System Interpreter>>Click on ..>>your interpreter path.

you can download python 3.8 from here : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Just introduce the path to it

Its work for me at pycharm version 2021.1